# SQL Simple SELECT Query

Tags: sql

```
create table Person(

SSN INT,
Name VARCHAR(20),
primary key(SSN)

);

create table Car(

PlateNr INT,
Model VARCHAR(20),
primary key(PlateNr)

);

create table CarOwner(

SSN INT,
PlateNr INT,
primary key(SSN, PlateNR)
foreign key(SSN) references Person (SSN),
foreign key(PlateNr) references Car (PlateNr)

);

Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456789','Max');
Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456787','John');
Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456788','Tom');


Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('123ABC','Volvo');
Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('321CBA','Toyota');
Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('333AAA','Honda');

Insert into CarOwner(SSN, PlateNr) VALUES ('123456789','123ABC');
Insert into CarOwner(SSN, PlateNr) VALUES ('123456787','333AAA');
```

The problem I'm having is the SELECTE query I wanna make. I wan't to be able to SELECT everything from the Person and wan't the include the PlateNr of the car he's the owner of, an example:

PERSON

```
---------------------------------
 SSN            NAME     Car

123456789       Max      123ABC
123456787       John     3338AAA
123456788       Tom      

----------------------------------
```

So, I want to be able to show everything from the Person table and display the content of CarOwner aswell if the person is in fact a CarOwner. What I have so far is: "SELECT * from Person, CarOwner WHERE Person.SSN = CarOwner.SSN;". But this obviously results in only showing the person(s) that are CarOwners.

Hope I explained me well enough, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN CarOwner co
ON p.SSN = co.SSN
LEFT OUTER JOIN Car c
ON co.PlateNr = c.PlateNr
```

Show [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20145/1/0)

P.S. I've changed the type of your primary key PlateNr (in varchar and not in int)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!. I'd love it, if you got time, to breifly explain it to me like I'm 5 what this query is acually doing. I haven't worked that much with JOINS unfortunately.

Comment: Please, you can study every SQL manual to understand better use of INNER and LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN. See here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Alright, yeah w3schools had a very good explaination. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh! Just thought of another thing I wan't to check out aswell. If I wanted to SELECT the person with an specific SSN. For example, WHERE SSN = '12356789'. How do you go about doing this?

Comment: add where condition at the end of your query

Answer (score 1):

select ssn, name, car

from Person p

LEFT OUTER JOIN CarOwner co

ON p.SSN = co.SSN

LEFT OUTER JOIN Car c

ON co.PlateNr = c.PlateNr